# Intel DG41WV IDE Port

Tags: hard-drive

I have a hard disk (ATA/IDE). Intel motherboard, Intel DG41WV, is there a port for connecting ATA hard disk. I can see 4 ports for SATA.  Is there a way to use the hard disk without using converters? (I tried ATA to SATA, but it was not working)

Answer (score -1):

According to Intel's [specifications for the DG41WV](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/motherboards/desktop-motherboards/desktop-board-dg41wv.html), parallel ATA (aka IDE) is not a feature of this motherboard.

An alternative is to use a USB enclosure that supports parallel ATA drives [such as this one](http://www.vantecusa.com/en/product/view_detail/250).

Comment: You can’t install Windows on a USB drive. ATA cards on PCI are widely available and the OP could use one of them.

Comment: @kinokijuf They never said they were installing Windows on it.  And even if they were considering it, installing your OS on a antiquated drive on a legacy controller is a terrible idea.